# Change dtype of column from object to datetime64

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I have a column with dates (Format: 2022-05-15) with the current **dtype: object**. I want to change the dtype to **datetime** with the following code:

```
df['column'] = pd.to_datetime(df['column'])
```

I receive the error:

```
ParserError: Unknown string format: DU2999
```

Im changing multible columns (e.g. another date column with **format dd-mm-yyyy hh-mm-ss**). I get the error only for the mentioned column.
Thank you very much for your help in advance.

Comment: that means one of the value in the column is DU2999, that to_datetime cannot infer in converting to a date/time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to handle this error by setting the resulting datetime value to NaT whenever the input value is "DU2999" (or another string that does not match the expected format), you can use:
`df['column'] = pd.to_datetime(df['column'], errors='coerce')`. See https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html.

If you want to manually correct this specific case, you could use `print(df.loc[df['column']=="DU2999"])` to view that row of the dataframe and decide what to overwrite it with.

Answer (score 0):

As @Naveed said there `invalid` date strings in `date column` such as `DU2999` . What you can do is simply find find out which strings that are not in date format.

```
temp_date = pd.to_datetime(df['Date_column'], errors='coerce', dayfirst=True)

mask = temp_date.isna()

out = df[mask]

#Problmeatic columns ==Filter columns with True values

df_problematic = out[ out.any(axis=1)] 
print(df_problematic)
```